Binding redirect (Machine.config) does not pick from GAC assemblies
I have been recently trying to setup a project that needs redirecting from Oracle.DataAccess version 2 to 4. I am trying to set this redirect to happen at the Windows machine.config level with the below entry.
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0-2.9999.9999.9999" newVersion="4.122.19.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

The program compiles just fine (I have Oracle.DataAccess as version 2 added as reference in the project), but at runtime I get the below logs
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Repositories\SafeGuard\SafeGuard\Web\Website\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\marinis.k\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/marinis.k/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/2e5d8de1/13ce5e54/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/marinis.k/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/2e5d8de1/13ce5e54/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Repositories/SafeGuard/SafeGuard/Web/Website/bin/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

What I am understanding is that it is not looking in GAC assemblies, otherwise I would get the below line in logs
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful. (or succesful)
GAC is where I have installed the Oracle dlls and I am not sure how to make my software look there.
As a matter of fact the response from VS Developer Command Promt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools>gacutil.exe /l 'Oracle.DataAccess'
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342, processorArchitecture=AMD64

Number of items = 3

Any ideas why is this happening and how could I fix the loading of the dlls?
Thanks everyone in advance
The only way this can work for now is if I manually add the v4 Oracle.DataAccess as a reference to the project.

I am not 100% sure, but I think you cannot redirect version 2 to 4. You can redirect only minor versions. What is the version of your database? Old 11.2 client may not be able to connect to your Oracle database server.
